# Jenkins Pipeline always fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline stages are all successful yet the build always says it failed. To be clear, the build was a success and I would like it to register with Jenkins as successful but for some reason Jenkins thinks it has failed. All the stages say success in the dashboard yet the build is marked with a red ball and the console output ends with `Finished: FAILURE`.

Here is my pipeline file

```
node {
    try{
        stage 'Clone repo'
        sh 'gcloud source repos clone <repo-name> --project=<project-name>'
        dir('<repo-name>') {
            try{
                stage 'Run tests'
                sh './gradlew test'
                stage 'Run integration tests'
                sh './gradlew integrationTest'
                publishHTML(target: [
                    allowMissing: false, 
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, 
                    keepAll: false, 
                    reportDir: '<repo-name>/build/reports/integrationTest', 
                    reportFiles: 'index.html', 
                    reportName: 'Integration Test Reports'])
            } finally {
                stage 'Stop and remove docker containers'
                sh 'docker-compose down'
                sh 'docker-compose rm -f'
            }
        }
    } finally {
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does Jenkins show a failure?  Does it give an error message?  In general, don't use the currentBuild.result option unless needed -- rely on the error('message') step and try/catch blocks (avoiding unexpected behavior).    Oh: I should mention that I am a developer who works on pipeline and maintains pipeline stage view here.

Comment: I only added those to try get it working. I removed them and it still fails. Do I need to add log messages that say success or something?

Comment: No, just don't catch the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I had included the full path to the html reports when I was actually inside a dir block. There was no indication in the logs of this.

Comment: Yes, if you swallow the exception, you lose this information.

Answer (score 1):

is your problem solved ?

Anyway the deleteDir function can be a problem sometimes. Because deleteDir recursively deletes the current directory and its contents, you can raise an error if you try to delete the complete job workspace.

Take care to use it in a dir function as below:

```
dir('directoryToDelete') {
    deleteDir()
}
```